# How is the constrict damage of the giant squid determined?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape

The base attack for the bite of the giant squid is 2D6+7 indicating it is a primary attack. The 'tentacles' attack is 4D6+3 indicating it is a secondary attack. However the constriction damage for the giant squid is 4D6+10, how did the developers come up with that?

Comment: @MikeQ [Please do not answer, even partially, in comments on this stack.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) Comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There are no hard rules on how to define constrict damage

And this irritates a lot of community members. Each developer simply decides what would be a reasonable damage for a monster's constrict ability when designing them. As such, we have a wild variety of constrict damage values, as can be seen on [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97763/animal-form-with-most-grapple-damage-in-wild-shape-form/98232#98232).

The description on [Constrict](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Constrict-Ex-) says that the damage is typically equal to the damage caused by the creature's attack:

> The amount of damage is given in the creature's entry and is **typically** equal to the amount of damage caused by the creature's melee attack.

But some creatures will treat the constrict as a primary natural attack and cause strength bonus times 1.5 (like the [assassin vine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/assassin-vine/)), others will cause strength bonus (like the [corpse lotus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/corpse-lotus/)), others will treat as secondary and cause half strength bonus (like the [giant octopus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/octopus/octopus-giant/)). Some creatures we have no explanation for the strenth bonus on their constrict damage, and we can't tell if they are primary, normal or secondary (like the [gray ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-gray/)). Others will cause a damage that is completely different from the attack that originated the constrict damage (like the [Yaoguai](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/yaoguai/)).

For the [Giant Squid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squid/giant-squid/) (and [a few others](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/sargassum-fiend/)), while the tentacles attack is considered a secondary attack (50% str bonus), the constrict ability is treated as a primary attack and gain 150% str bonus instead of only 50%.

Comment: Can Strong Jaw  be applied to the 'Constriction'? Or does it have to be something like 'Tentacles' or 'Bite'?

Comment: @Atalius that is a good (new) question. :P