# What feats give maximum melee damage per round for wild-shaped druid?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, druid, wild-shape, melee-combat

Building a level 11 druid. Plan to be in most combat situations while wild-shaped. What feats can I take to maximize melee damage/per turn?

Already looking into Eldritch Claws to ensure that the damage bypasses magic and silver damage reduction.

All paizo material is in effect, as well as [the popular Feat Tax rules found here](http://michaeliantorno.com/item/feat-taxes-in-pathfinder/).

After level and items, STR is 22 (+6).

Comment: Which “popular Feat Tax rules” are you referring to?

Comment: I'll edit it in

Comment: You may want to narrow down your question, asking "how to get the best damage as a druid" is too broad and might result in several answers working best for certain combinations and situations. To prove this, see this related question: [Animal form with most grapple damage in wild shape form](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97763/animal-form-with-most-grapple-damage-in-wild-shape-form).